# Spoon with serial number of devices

Tags: android, spoon

Is it possible to specify the serial numbers to execute with specific devices ?

I have attached 10 devices.  But i wanted to run only 5 devices.

Is there any option to give specific Device IDs and run them ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you use this gradle plugin:

https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin

Then you can specify in your build.gradle

```
spoon {
  devices = ['333236E9AE5800EC']
}
```